# Entity Framework 6 Create model from existing table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We have to maintain a very old application.
There is an old part (all data access is handled with stored procedures) and since my predecessors took over the application, they started to build a new part for the new requirements which uses entity framework 6.

Now the customer has a new requirement that needs access to one of the tables for which there isn't an EF-model yet.

Is there an easy way to automatically create an EF-model from an existing database table? (**I only want this one table, not the whole remaining database!**)
Do you know of any tool that can achieve this or do I have to write it by hand?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are two different styles of answers below, one assumes you are using Code First, the other assumes you are working with an Entity Data Model (edmx) file.  You didn't specify what format of model is desired.

Comment: Hello @pseudocoder you are right. I am using Code First. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use **EF Power Tools** which is a plugin for Visual Studio.

[Download here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d/)

With the plugin, you can reverse engineer your database in order to create your objects and mappings in your application.  Despite the fact that it will save you a lot of time, note that it is not perfect.  You might want to review your indexes and relationships as some were missing in my case.

To Reverse engineer your database, it's as simple as this:

> The Reverse Engineer Code First command is used to generate the POCO,
>   mapping (configuration), and derived DbContext classes that are based
>   on an existing database.
>
> - Right click the project and select **Entity Framework –> Reverse
>     Engineer Code First**.
> - Enter the information about an existing database
>     based on which you want to reverse engineer Code First.

You can check this link from Microsoft for a complete example:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj593170.aspx

**IMPORTANT:** As of Entity Framework 7 (not released yet), only the **Code First** approach will be used. You might want to consider this before choosing another approach like Model First, for instance.  You can read more about: [EF7 - What Does “Code First Only” Really Mean](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/10/21/ef7-what-does-code-first-only-really-mean.aspx)

Comment: As I understand EF 7 isn't a direct successor of EF 6. EF 7 is a completely different path than EF6, and is now a lightweight version of EF6. Over time EF 7 will get those features as well. So don't rely your solution on wether you should chooce EF 6 or EF 7.

Comment: I faced a lot of limitations when I inherited from a Model First project. I read a ton of posts about EF and limitations and decided we would go to Code Firt.  You might want to check Rowan Miller's blog (romiller.com) and find other member of the EF team and follow their work.  I don't have an explicit list.  I just Google a lot! :-)

Comment: @jonas: I agree with you.  But if you are to start a project NOW, I think you really do want to consider it.  It might not be a "direct successor" but it won't be a different product and migration will be possible. I would want that migration to be as smooth as possible.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thank you! Altough it would have been nice to be able to select which tables to create the code & maps for :P

Comment: If you have so many tables, you might want to create a new DB from your actual DB with only the tables you need.

Comment: @Maxime "We won’t be pushing EF7 as the ‘go-to release’ for all platforms at the time of the initial release to support ASP.NET 5. EF7 will be the default data stack for ASP.NET 5 applications, but we will not recommend it as an alternative to EF6 in other applications until we have more functionality implemented.” source: http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/tsneed/when-should-you-make-the-move-to-entity-framework-7

Comment: Well, you are missing the next sentence that is "Given that ASP.NET 5 is in the same ‘part v1 and part v7’ position as EF, the missing features will be less of an issue. We will of course be working to make them available ASAP." (source: http://goo.gl/ClSruU). I understand that they will release often. You might want to read "EF7 – v1 or v7?" from Rowan Miller: http://goo.gl/Xk1Qrf . Information is pretty complete. :-)

Comment: @downvoter Any specific reason so it can be adjusted ?

Answer (score 3):

Open the Entity Data Model (edmx) file (edit: or create one if you don't already have one), right click on the design surface in a blank area, and select "Update Model from Database".

Select the proper connection string if prompted, then choose the "Add" tab, and drill down to the tables in your database you want to add and put a check mark by them.  Click Finish and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the EF power tools plugin which give you context menus for `Reverse Engineer Code First` as well as other code generate options

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just create an EDMX and only have it select the tables you want it to point to instead of the whole DB?

Look at Generate From Database in this article

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx